# Wordpress - How can I sort admin area by column in the table

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a manually post type in Wordpress called mypost. I write a php file for that post
I have special table in my database for mypost, there I save all mypost details.
I have a column called disp_order, I view mypost order by disp_order on the site.
**I need to sort the the post in the admin area by same disp_order column.**

Is there any way to make the admin area take the details of mypost table instead of the WP posts table?
Do I must add a meta attribute to do so?
if I must add meta, which code  I need to add to php file of the custom mypost?

Is there any good url that explain everything I need to do in order to build custom page with php code and then make the admin  area sort by specific column of that post table?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code you've written already?

Comment: I tried to use the code as mention in the answer in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1853/automatically-sorting-cust
om-post-type-admin-area-by-a-custom-field. when I do it I get empty list. I think it because it go to the general post table and not to the  specific table of that custom post. I want to sort by field (disp_order) that exist only in the specific table of the post and not in general post table.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I tried to sort by mysql column and not by meta_key.
I add meta_key and then defined as in the [url](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1853/automatically-sorting-custom-post-type-admin-area-by-a-custom-field)

```
if (is_admin()) {

        // Present the posts in your meta_key field's order in admin

        if (isset($query->query_vars['post_type'])) {
            if ($query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'gs_events') {

                $query->set('meta_key', 'gs_event_date');
                $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
                $query->set('order', 'ASC');

     }
}
```

I change in the above, the

```
$query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
```

to

```
$query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
```

For setting it ordered numericly.